BufferQueue has been abandoned
2024-05-02 14:11:35.000 31529-31584 BufferQueueProducer     com.dd.mvoteliveness2                E  [SurfaceView[com.dd.mvoteliveness2/com.dd.mvoteliveness2.LiveBridge]#2(BLAST Consumer)2](id:7b2900000003,api:0,p:-1,c:31529) dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
2024-05-02 14:11:35.000 31529-31584 Surface                 com.dd.mvoteliveness2                E  dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
2024-05-02 14:11:35.000 31529-31584 Surface                 com.dd.mvoteliveness2                E  Surface::unlockAndPost failed, no locked buffer
2024-05-02 14:11:35.001 31529-31584 BufferQueueProducer     com.dd.mvoteliveness2                E  [SurfaceView[com.dd.mvoteliveness2/com.dd.mvoteliveness2.LiveBridge]#2(BLAST Consumer)2](id:7b2900000003,api:0,p:-1,c:31529) query: BufferQueue has been abandoned
2024-05-02 14:11:35.001 31529-31584 BufferQueueProducer     com.dd.mvoteliveness2                E  [SurfaceView[com.dd.mvoteliveness2/com.dd.mvoteliveness2.LiveBridge]#2(BLAST Consumer)2](id:7b2900000003,api:0,p:-1,c:31529) query: BufferQueue has been abandoned
2024-05-02 14:11:35.002 31529-31584 libc                    com.dd.mvoteliveness2                A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6d2d12bd00 in tid 31584 (ImageReader-128), pid 31529 (.mvoteliveness2)


I'm expecting to get status result and image on final display of the app after processing but my application crashes and restarts instead of showing results.
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    scrfdncnn.resetGlobalVariables();

    new CountDownTimer(3000, 3000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            cameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            cameraView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            scrfdncnn.closeCamera();
            Log.d("TAG", "onFinish: firf ");
            livenessMessage = scrfdncnn.livenessResult();

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(livenessMessage);
                int status = jsonObject.getInt("status");
                String reason = jsonObject.getString("reason");
                String image = jsonObject.getString("image");

                if (status == 200 || status == 202) {
                    imageBitmap = scrfdncnn.sendImage();
                    byte[] imageData = getByteArray(imageBitmap);
                    imageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    livenessMessage = "{\"status\":" + status + ",\"reason\":\"" + reason
                            + "\",\"image\":\"" + imageBase64 + "\"}";
                } else {
                    imageBitmap = scrfdncnn.sendImage();
                    byte[] imageData = getByteArray(imageBitmap);
                    imageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    livenessMessage = "{\"status\":" + status + ",\"reason\":\"" + reason
                            + "\",\"image\":\"" + imageBase64 + "\"}";
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            resultOpenFun(livenessMessage);
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surfaceDestroyed = true; // Set the flag to indicate SurfaceTexture destruction
    scrfdncnn.resetGlobalVariables();
    cameraView.getHolder().removeCallback(this); // Remove callback to avoid further interactions
}

